# ISSUU change the default 'Click to read' text on a PDF

Tags: issuu

Like in the topic: Is there a way to change this text? When I embed the code on my site the generated structure is flash and I can't access it. The only exception is the Chromium Browser which generates  element and I can change the text via JS. But can I do something with the flash content or change this text somewhere on the issuu account page before publishing the content?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Issuu viewer, haven't tryed it yet, but have a look at these pages, they should point you in the right direction:

http://developers.issuu.com/customize/

Especially changing language and stuff shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: This text cannot be changed there